# html2canvas exported image has lower brightness

Tags: html, css, html2canvas

I'm using `html2canvas` to create a downloaded image, but the generated image from `html2canvas` has lower brightness.

this is my code

```js
html2canvas($("#downloadArea")[0], {
  scale: 2,
}).then((canvas) => {
  const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = imgData.replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
  a.download = "Download.jpg";
  a.click();
```

This is preview of my page:

Source image
[image: source image]

Generated image by `html2canvas`
[image: generated image by html2canvas]

Is there any configuration for increase contrast or keep the contrast on generated image?

I have try to adding a filter styling, but it's `filter` css not support on `html2canvas`

Comment: Maybe try to use the low brightness/contrast image then use image processing library like jimp or other to increase it?

Comment: Do you have the same problem using a lossless format like png ?

Comment: that's not image, but chart from chart.js, i haven't try using other library like jimpp, and when i using other format like png, it was same. Actually i create a picture using html2canvas and then convert it to .pdf using jsPdf. And exported file from jsPdf convert my picture to lower brightness.